# Can't block spam email from a very specific email account on hotmail

Tags: spam-prevention, outlook.com

I am receiving spam email from a specific email address for some time now. The email account has obviously been hijacked and abandoned. However that's not the problem. I have attempted to block this one email address by removing it from my contacts list and adding it to the blocked list but for some reason it always comes back and is never blocked. I have done this many times and each time, a few days later, it comes right back sending me spam.

Anyone know what I can do to permanently block this address?

Answer (score 3):

I'd also report the sender IP/email address to [SpamCop](http://www.spamcop.net/anonsignup.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is to make sure you don't have any e-mails from this address stashed away in some folder in Hotmail. If so try deleting it and see if that helps.

Comment: Or you might have previously marked it as **Not junk**.